# in ramfs, how can i trace file access pattern in terms of NUMA node?

Tags: filesystems, numa

Since `Ramfs` stores files into memory and that memory is bound to certain `NUMA` node, I think there exist some ways to keep track of `nodes` that requested a file(`a.txt` for example).

For example, if there are **4 NUMA** nodes with its local memory, list of nodes that accessed `a.txt` could be `0 0 0 1 1 0 2 2 2 0 3 3 3 3 3`.

One possible solution might be as following:

1. Find low-level `ramfs` file operation function(like `read` or `write`)
2. Get the node number of the thread that is executing that function
3. Store that node number into somewhere (like `inode` of a.txt or something)

But I failed to find such a low-level function of ramfs and I can't go ahead.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What is Ramfs? Is it Linux? Is your machine NUMA (there are more than 1 socket and each socket has own integrated memory controller)? NUMA places physical 4KB (or 2MB) pages. There is libnuma for linux (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/numa.3.html) and if data from Ramfs is `mmap`ed, to find where data is you may try `numa_move_pages`/`move_pages` (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/move_pages.2.html) with NULL in nodes: "nodes can also be NULL, in which case move_pages() does not move any pages but instead will return the node where each page currently resides, in the status array."

Comment: my question is: how can i know which node required the data, not in which node the data resides. more specifically, i want to keep log for each file(for each inode) in Ramfs. the log is list of NUMA nodes and will tell us which node(s) accessed the file.

Comment: Bot, please explain more. Is it Linux (which kernel version)? Is it tmpfs? How file/files are accessed by program (is it read, mmap, write, or what). Is it your program (can you modify it) or many not your programs? What can you change (patch+recompile kernel, patch ramfs-compatible module, FUSE; can you use ftrace/stap/dprobe/strace/ltrace? You can't store too much in the inode. (PS if it is task from your course, tell us what was this course about, kernel programming or unix programming or what?)

Comment: thanks for your kindness it's like i will visit stackoverflow very often. Basically i am freshman in graduate school and i study on NUMA effect of (future) large scale nonVolatile memory-based filesystem. I thought i need to be aware general memory-based filesystem's file access pattern(in terms of NUMA node). So i chose Ramfs(since i had to assume no disk device). My linux version is 4.7.4(i can boot with other kernel version if needed). It's only about Ramfs not Tmpfs so i don't even need to consider disk.

Comment: A program(which i made myself but since i want to know the general file access pattern, i will also test benchmark programs or general applications like tensorflow) accesses files(files in Ramfs-mounted directory) with simple read and write. I think i can try patch ramfs-compatible modules but i know nothing about FUSE. I tried ftrace to keep track of ramfs write but for some reason, "ramfs.write" was not seen(because i am poor at ftrace).

Comment: I know inode structre should not be large. In fact, i only want to know certain file's file access history(it doesn't have to be in that file's inode. Any place is okay or simply printk() them is okay.)

Comment: Ok, (still emulating FS on NVM memory sounds strange) you may try to hack into ramfs implementation http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.7.4/source/fs/ramfs/inode.c, file ops are `.readpage = simple_readpage, .write_begin = simple_write_begin, .write_end = simple_write_end,` (they are generic implementations from libfs) and it has no variant to be compiled as module. You may try to use some kprobes / kernel tracepoints to hook on the implementation, but hooking into generic methods is not something I would recommend. You may try to rewrite ramfs info something other with your impl.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! I'm gonna do something in simple_readpage, simple_write_begin, simple_write_end. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete solution, but some ideas.

> *some*fs stores files into memory and that memory is bound to certain NUMA node, .. I think there exist some ways to keep track of nodes that requested a file

There are many methods to trace file access (some basic kinds of; open/read/write/mmap; *but not the usage of mmaped regions*) in modern Linux (4.x kernels). For single pid you may use `strace` system call tracer (or `ltrace -S` which additionaly can catch library calls). For many pids (full system tracing) you may try `sysdig`.

There are in-kernel (and out-of-tree kernel-mode) tracing frameworks which can be used too. Like something based on perf + probe / ftrace (trace-cmd), or more advanced tracing solution like `stap`/`dtrace`/`lttng` with corresponding tracepoints defined and enabled. Gregg in his [presentations](https://www.slideshare.net/brendangregg/) and [site](http://www.brendangregg.com/) lists more tools, both classic (with small list for VFS) https://www.slideshare.net/brendangregg/linux-systems-performance-2016#slide=7; and bcc/eBPF based: https://www.slideshare.net/brendangregg/designing-tracing-tools-67693476#slide=3.

Most of system-wide tools already have good frameworks to do timestamps and process accounting and to download lot of tracing data from kernel-mode into some log/dump file. Some of them (stap/dtrace/bcc + probes) allow you to write small code fragment to execute when traced function is called.

Example of Gregg's tool is "iosnoop" (this on is on top of `debugfs & /sys/kernel/debug/tracing` which is [ftrace](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt) & [`trace-cmd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/trace-cmd.1.html)). It shows latency of every **real** read/write operation (which goes to real disk; not access to already read data in page cache, like it is in ramfs):

- doc http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-07-16/iosnoop-for-linux.html,
- src https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/iosnoop
- (works almost anywhere by `nop ftraceing` two events:   events/block/block_rq_insert and  events/block/block_rq_complete)
- (add debugging save of raw trace by replacing in iosnoop src the `cat trace` line as `cat trace | tee -a ~/iotrace.$$.dump` and take a look into it)

> 1. find low level ramfs file operation function(like read or write)

Unfortunately, ramfs is too basic FS to implement anything interesting. There are address space operations and file operations for ramfs:

http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.7.4/source/fs/ramfs/inode.c#L46

```
static const struct address_space_operations ramfs_aops = {
    .readpage   = simple_readpage,
    .write_begin    = simple_write_begin,
    .write_end  = simple_write_end,
    .set_page_dirty = __set_page_dirty_no_writeback,
};
```

http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.7.4/source/fs/ramfs/file-mmu.c#L33

```
const struct file_operations ramfs_file_operations = {
    .read_iter  = generic_file_read_iter,
    .write_iter = generic_file_write_iter,
    .mmap       = generic_file_mmap,
    .fsync      = noop_fsync,
    .splice_read    = generic_file_splice_read,
    .splice_write   = iter_file_splice_write,
    .llseek     = generic_file_llseek,
};
```

`simple_` / `generic_file_` operations are defined in libfs/ or mm/ (with elixir/lxr web sites you can just click on function to find its definition and usage) http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.7.4/source/fs/libfs.c#L409, and they are used in several more linux FS implementations, so it can be unsafe to unconditionally trace them all.

You may try to rewrite implementation of ramfs; just define similar `simple_` / `generic_file_` operations inside your variant with different name. You will be able to trace only them.

> 2. get the node number of the thread that is executing that function

I think, there is another approach to this. Get the pid/tid of process/thread when access is detected; but don't do anything to find NUMA node (it is possible is you will modify ramfs implementation and adds your own variants of `aops` with reading of `current` ptr and finding the NUMA Node from [`struct task_struct`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.7.4/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1458); but where to write it?).

What is easier when there is advanced tracing framework - is to record all actions of scheduler - when and which pid was planned to every CPU (like in [kernelshark](http://elinux.org/images/6/64/Elc2011_rostedt.pdf) or in perf/stap/lttng tracing of `sched_` functions - `sched_switch` with arguments probably; even ftrace will allow you to combine two tracing, both io and sched in single filter).

You will have some postprocess to sort output and combine info, but this should do the task

> 3. store that node number into somewhere(like inode of a.txt or something)

Don't reinvent the wheel, use tracing frameworks.

Comment: For real disks also blktrace: https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~aaronc/iosched/doc/blktrace.html (per-cpu tracing into dump files viewable with blkparse)